# Azure Document Client ignores JsonProperty attribute

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, .net-4.7.2

I use Azure Function app. In app I use package Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB v2.9.2 to work with CommosDB. My entity is:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class MyLog : Entity
{
    [JsonProperty("createDate")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize `MyLog` with `Newtonsoft.Json` I see that `CreateDate` property is camel case style and looks exactly as mentioned in `JsonProperty`, but when I write my entity to CosmosDB via `CreateDocumentAsync` method I see that `CreateDate` now is pascal case and looks like `CreateDate`. Want to mention that there is no `ContractResolver` used. I can not find any other place where pascal case can be applied to entity serialization.

**[UPDATE]**

When I run tests I see that property naming in DB is correct (taking into account JsonProperty). It is wrong only when azure func writes to DB

```
var policy = new ConnectionPolicy();
policy.PreferredLocations.Add("Germany North");
documentClient = new DocumentClient(endPoint, key, policy);
await documentClient.OpenAsync();
```

...

```
await documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName), document);
```

**[/UPDATE]**

Can someone suggest what other options can result in such behavior?

Comment: Why do you need the document fields to be camel-case within CosmosDB?

Comment: @Oliver actually I do not make decisions here, I do refactoring of existing project and just need to find out reason of this behavior.

Comment: Has a custom serializer been configured as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclientoptions.serializer?view=azure-dotnet)?

Comment: @Oliver mentioned doc uses a bit different client, in my case it is DocumentClient, but in options there is no special serializer specified, moreover when I run tests I see that property naming in DB is correct. It is wrong only when azure func writes to DB

Comment: Ok, could you post your `DocumentClient` code in addition to the POCOs you've detailed?

Comment: @Oliver updated questing with code of DocumentClient creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found out the reason of this behavior. Azure Function v1 with .NET 4.7.2 uses by default DataContractJsonSerializer and JsonProperty attribute is not taken into account. Tests use NewtonSoft json serializer and that's why attributes are used.

Comment: I've just come back to have another look at this.  Glad you've sorted it.  Is there any documentation you can reference in your answer?